# In my php script, my connection to the server works but my sql queries do not

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

The connection works, I don't get a connection error. But when I run the script I get an undefined index error and it outputs "0 results" although my table is populated for sure and I am searching for something that I know is in the table.

I am using MySQL workbench to manage the database and apache (xampp) to host the local server and run the PHP scripts. Could this be the problem? Is there a way for me to host the database in the same place as the apache website?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM book_table WHERE Title LIKE $input OR Author LIKE $input OR Barcode LIKE $input";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_all()) {
     echo "<br>Title: " . $row["Title"]. " - Author: " . $row["Author"];
 }
} else {
 echo " <br> 0 results";
}
```

Comment: Check the syntax of `LIKE`.

Comment: You're probably not escaping your variables. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param. It will prevent SQL injection, and eliminate any quoting issues you may be having.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion to you is [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname;//$dbName is the name of your database
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';//use your login information here
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user,$pass);
$query = "SELECT * FROM book_table WHERE Title LIKE :info OR Author LIKE :info OR Barcode LIKE :info";
$ps = $db->prepare($query);
$ps->bindValue(':info', $input)
$ps->execute();
$result = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//iterate over result
if (!empty($results)){
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "<br>Title: " . $row["Title"]. " - Author: " . $row["Author"];
    }
} else {
    echo " <br> 0 results";
}
```

Also, remember to use the MySQL `LIKE` in the right way. When you want to match a part of a String, you need to use the `%` symbol.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM book_table WHERE Title LIKE "%goodbook%"
```

It will return all rows that has the "goodbook" as part of the Title.

Comment: Don't you need to `bindValue` also?

Comment: Yes. Thanks to note it

Comment: I tried this solution and it still did not work, my database is probably the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this. Since you use `mysqli_*` I have make it prepared statements and `bind_param`.

Note: Not tested. So may need to adjust a bit.

```
$param = '$input';
$sql= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM book_table WHERE Title LIKE ? OR Author LIKE ? OR Barcode LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $param);
$sql->execute();

if($res->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $res->fetch()) {          
         echo "<br>Title: " . $row["Title"]. " - Author: " . $row["Author"];          
   }
} else { 
      echo " <br> 0 results"; 
}
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions in this thread and they all dont work, there must be something wrong with my database then.

Comment: @KimonP yes, there is something else then because those at least one of those solutions should work. Did you get some error message or anything?

Comment: No i got no error messages. Maybe the database is empty for some reason.

Comment: @KimonP , do you still have the problem? If yes, can you show your connection to database?